# Issue with triggering the submit function with included js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-events

I'm have a problem triggering the form submission. I am setting the form into `<div id="access"></div>` innerHTML using the included js file in the header of page. As:

```
<div id="access">
    <form method="post" id="acc">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

The form submission is implementing in the included js file in the header, but they are not listening my submit function, which is implemented as:

```
$('#acc').submit(function(){
  alert("dsds");
  return false;
});
```

Same js function also not working in the same file. How can I make it listen the above  `lead_form` submission?

Comment: use jquery document ready function.... your js is being loaded before the html

Comment: try using `$(document).on("submit", "#acc", function(){    });`

Comment: yes i had use document.ready too.. in the both files. but still it's not taking effect. so now i am using the $(function() {  });

Comment: vijay thanx for ur code. its work in the same file. but its not working in the included js file. i have tried with the $(function() { }); and $(document).ready(function() { });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because jQuery's selector only acts on elements that exist on the page at the time it's ran.

Instead, use the jQuery.on() function.

```
$('#access').on('submit', '#acc', function() { /* Your code here. */ });
```

**Edit**  For some clarification:  '#access' exists at run-time, so therefore you can bind an event to it, which then refers to it's child element '#acc'.  Keep in mind that the context of 'this' while in the anonymous function will refer to '#acc' and not '#access', despite using the $('#access') selector.